# Consent UI creation for Windows 10 app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop

I am developing Windows 10 app. For User account information capability, I need to add consent UI. I just want to know whether some API is already available to display consent UI or we have to design the consent UI to get the consent from the user.

Comment: Usually with addition of capabilities like for `location` it adds a consent UI by itself. Earlier Windows used to ask specifically to add these UI consent but with addition of inbuilt ones its been reduced considerably. Like on Live authentication it shows what all permissions are being provided etc

Comment: any API available to show consent UI?

Comment: Dont think there are any you can either use popup or a message dialog box

Comment: Consent UI should be displayed only once when launching app for the first time. I just want to know how to do that incase if we use popup or message box.

Comment: For this developers create a page with consent UI. Now they store a flag in Local Storage of app. If flag is false for first run then navigate to UI page and change flag else navigate to content page.

Comment: @Jerin Your comments are very useful. I would be more happy to accept if you put it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comments**
Usually with addition of capabilities like for location it adds a consent UI by itself.
 Earlier Windows used to ask specifically to add these UI consent but with addition of inbuilt ones its been reduced considerably.
 Like on Live authentication it shows what all permissions are being provided, or before installing app it shows the consent UI based on capabilities mentioned, followed by other consent UI like for location as popup or a message dialog box once they are called first time in app.
Developers can also create a page with consent UI. They can store a flag in Local Storage of app. If flag is false for first run then navigate to consent UI page and change flag else navigate to content page/Instructions Page.

Answer (score 1):

For user consent about specific things like "Store your Location" or "Save Password" , you need to ask the user via a **MesageBox** or some **custom control**
There is no default template for this. Consent messages are inbuilt for Camera, GPS and the hardware devices which need user attention before executing.